# What might I be?

Tags: riddle, word

Try to figure out the word:

> You can bend me.
>   I am the opposite of heavy.
>   You can try to stop me, but I'll always find a way.
>   Without me, you wouldn't have eyes.
>   With me, you can worship beauty.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> light

You can bend me.

> a black hole can bend light. We can do it too in a fiber optic cable.

I am the opposite of heavy.

> light does not weight

You can try to stop me, but I'll always find a way.

> if you try to stop it with your hand, it will go in between your fingers. I am not sure about that one.

Without me you would'nt have eyes.

> without light eyes are useless

With me you can worship beauty.

> with light we can see the beauty around us

Comment: You can also bend light using mirrors :)

Comment: +1 correct :). The part of always finding a way is mostly that theoretically light can penetrate objects too, even tho with the human eye you can't always see, light penetrates almost everything to a certain degree. Of course there are situations where you can fully cancel the light particles passing through matter.